# VBA error 424 Object Required but only one some PCs

Tags: vba, object, ms-word, required

We use an external software database which generates an Word document and will run a Visual Basic Script to enter date and time which are added into the Word document.

This works on some machines and on other it won't. Strangely it works on the newer machines whit a newer image of Windows. We install our computer using a AIK-Server. There are 2 images on that server one for the newer computers and and older one from 2017. So now i try to figure out what is missing in the older one.

The code generates the 424 error while running the second entry of this subroutine:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
dtp_datum.Value = Date

End Sub
```

I doubt it is an error of the script, because it is working on the newer ones. I think that something is missing, like a Runtime library or Plug-in. But i cant figure out what. The never image is based on the older one, so it must be something added to the new image.

The image contains Windows 7, Office 2010 Pro, Novell Groupwise, and some default programs like Adobe reader and Firefox. Updated to the latest version of W7 and Office using WSUS.

Comment: What is `dtp_datum`?

Comment: I think a Variable. It is not declared somewhere else.

Comment: I suspect `dtp_datum` is an Active-X control on the `UserForm` (maybe a date picker?) that either isn't present or isn't registered on the older machines.

Comment: How could i check this?